# Adding additional xml attributes to a subelement python

Tags: python, xml, attributes, elementtree

I am trying to read a processed xml and add a 4th attribute to it using elementtree.

```
<ID_List>
 <Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Attribute Name="SampleID" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="ListNumber" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="TestID" Value="ABCDEFGHIJK"/>
 </Sample>
</ID_List>
```

my code so far

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=<path>)
root = tree.getroot()
for subelem in root[2]: # IDlist is root[0], Samples is root[1] need to add attribute to root[3] sample
    for subelem2 in subelem:
        subelem2.set("Name", "4th attribute")
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To add a new Attribute tag just append the new tag:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as et

x = """<ID_List>
 <Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Attribute Name="SampleID" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="ListNumber" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="TestID" Value="ABCDEFGHIJK"/>
 </Sample>
 </Samples>
</ID_List>"""

xml = et.fromstring(x)

tag = xml.find(".//Samples/Sample")
new = et.Element("Attribute", dict(Name="Foo", Value="12345"))
tag.append(new)

print(et.tostring(xml))
```

Which would give you:

```
<ID_List>
 <Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Attribute Name="SampleID" Value="0000000" />
    <Attribute Name="ListNumber" Value="0000000" />
    <Attribute Name="TestID" Value="ABCDEFGHIJK" />
 <Attribute Name="Foo" Value="12345" />
</Sample>
 </Samples>
</ID_List>
```

To update the file:

```
In [4]: cat test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ID_List>
 <Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Attribute Name="SampleID" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="ListNumber" Value="0000000"/>
    <Attribute Name="TestID" Value="ABCDEFGHIJK"/>
 </Sample>
 </Samples>
</ID_List>
In [5]: from xml.etree import cElementTree as et

In [6]: xml = et.parse("test.xml")

In [7]: tag = xml.find(".//Samples/Sample")

In [8]: tag.append(et.Element("Attrbute",{"Name":"Foo","Value":"12345"}))

In [9]: xml.write("test.xml")

In [10]: cat test.xml
<ID_List>
 <Samples>
  <Sample>
    <Attribute Name="SampleID" Value="0000000" />
    <Attribute Name="ListNumber" Value="0000000" />
    <Attribute Name="TestID" Value="ABCDEFGHIJK" />
 <Attrbute Name="Foo" Value="12345" /></Sample>
 </Samples>
</ID_List>
```

Comment: I want to add a new attribute tag but i want to do this from an xml file and not a string.

Comment: I used the string as an example,   the logic is exactly the same reading from a file.

Comment: I keep getting an 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag' error

Comment: Thanks that worked. What if I had several sample nodes under samples and wanted to add the 4th attribute to all of them?

Comment: Just use findAll and loop over the result appending a new Tag for each, I will add an example in a minute

Comment: Disregard previous question.Just used findall Thanks for everything!